# Как в модели django для foreign key поля сделать дополнительно условие выборки?

Tags: python, django, model

Есть 2 модели:

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    value = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class B(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, primary_key=True)
    version = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    a_value = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при обращении к полю a_value в модели B учитывалось поле version? Грубо говоря вместо

```
A.objects.get(pk=self.a_value)
```

выполнялось

```
A.objects.get(pk=self.a_value, version=self.version)
```

Мне в голову пришло использование property, но может быть есть более изящный способ?

Comment: `B.objects.get(id=<нужный id>, a_value__version=<нужное число>)`

Comment: Нет, я хочу чтобы при обращении к полю a_value, оно уже было выбрано с учетом version.
b = B.objects.get(pk=1)
av = b.a_value
av - должно учесть как id так и version. Своего рода двойной ключ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оставил вариант использования property и переопределил его getter.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правилно понял вопрос, то думаю Subquery решит эту проблему (Django 1.11+)

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

b = B.objects.filter(a_value__pk=OuterRef('pk'), version=OuterRef('version'))
A.objects.filter(b__pk__in=Subquery(b.values('pk')))
```

Не тестировал, но думаю задумка ясна. Дальше там уже по ситуации, можно просто в менеджеры добавить, например.

Comment: Нет) Смотрите, когда есть поле типа ForeignKey, то при обращении к нему модель автоматически возвращает запись из таблицы, с которой связано это поле по ключу. Т.е. есть связь, есть поле которое содержит ключ к таблице А, но так же есть поле version, которое я хотел бы использовать для уточнения связи. И чтобы это было сделано без явного использования фильтров.
Чтобы при обращении к полю a_value, уже была сделана связь с учетом первичного ключа и дополнительно поля version.

Comment: @sidsukana sidsukana,  это несколько странно, у модели B может быть только один F(k) -> A, соответственно, что должно происходить, в случае если version не совпадает, должен вернуться None? В таком случае да, лучше, через property

Comment: Система расчитана на то что не должно быть несуществующих связей :) Но все равно спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @sidsukana sidsukana, я думаю тогда все гораздо проще, вообще убрать поле version из модели B, оно там просто ни к чему, тем более, что a_value является обязательным т.е. мы просто берем version для B  у A и все